# Update to my Android application is not downloading

Tags: android, download

I uploaded an application to the market and yesterday I uploaded a newer version.
The version number is one higher so that it should download it automatically.

However, it has been well over a day and a half and my phone still hasn't updated.
What could I have done wrong?

Comment: Did you use the same signing key?

Comment: i think it might just be the market acting up. my app's first update took well over 6 hours to show up, and the update's date didn't change at all until my second update. Also, do the Android market website show the same thing as the mobile one? I've noticed that they are sometimes out of sync with each other.

Comment: @Pyrodante Definitely used the same key - I only have one.

Comment: @Kevin I have a small update to add so maybe I will upload a new version tomorrow and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one:  Do you mean that when you manually go to market, you don't see an update as being available?  This might be a result of having left the uploaded version as a draft instead of saving it.  What do you see when you look at it in the Web version of market?

If you mean it hasn't *automatically* downloaded behind the scenes - Assuming the app is set to update automatically in the first place, that setting will be reset if a required permissions are added to the update of an app.  If you think about it, if you downloaded a flashlight application that required no permissions except the ability to keep the screen on, and set it to auto-update, you'd want that auto-update revoked if a new version was pushed that required SMS messaging, right?

If you haven't added any permissions, ANOTHER possibility (I've done this one a couple times) is that you have the development version on your phone, *not* a version downloaded from public market.  Market won't update that for you, you'll have to uninstall it and download the app fresh from Market.

If none of these are the solution, it might just be that local cache hasn't been refreshed.  Wait it out, or manually go to market and download the update.

Comment: When I look at the version on the market it shows the new one. I haven't tried downloading it directly since I wanted to check that the automatic update actually works. The version on my phone is definitely the market version - I know because I have an option in the preferences screen that I automatically turn off when saving for the market. Thinking about it I see that I have had no updates for any of my applications in the last 2 days. I'll wait it out and see.